# Empty page in Webmatrix

Tags: webmatrix

I wrote (copied) a first program in WebMatrix. I selected EmptySite template and in Page.cshtml I typed 2 lines. Finaly, the code in Page.cshtml looks like this:

```
 @{

  }

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html lang="en">
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <title></title>
     </head>
     <body>
          <h1>Welcome to the WebMatrix!</h1>
          <p>I began to become a web developer on @DateTime.Now.ToString()</p>
     </body>
  </html>
```

I pressed "Run" but I got an empty web-page. Nothing is written on it. I received  no error message.

Well, what's wrong ?

Thanx,

Eb_Cj

Comment: What is the full URL that your browser is going to?

Comment: @Polynomial - Is "http://localhost:25776/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be going to the default document rather than your page. You can solve this in two ways: either right click on the `Page.cshtml` node in the project explorer within WebMatrix and select **Launch in browser** or manually change the URL in your browser to `localhost:25776/Page`.

Comment: There is a third way: press CTRL+F12 when the page is displayed in the editor window.